# Find all ids that have 2 specific values for a one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains data of employees, their managers and the projects they worked on. The dataframe (a bit simplified) looks like this:

```
    EmployeeID  ManagerID  ProjectID
0            2         18        111
1            3         17        111
2            2         17        119
3            3         22        121
4            6         22        121
5            6         18        111
6            6         17        113
7            6         17        116
```

I would like get all employees that have both worked with manager 17 and 18, in this case that would be employee 2 and employee 6.

I know I can write a query to get all employees that worked with either manager 17 or 18 using:

```
df.query('ManagerID == 17 | ManagerID == 18')
```

But now I would need to find all employees that have worked with bot, since the combination of a employee - manager can be found multiple times in the dataframe I can't use a count. I think I would need an self join, but I don't really know how that can be done in pandas.

Comment: Sorry for wrongly closed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for all `EmployeeID` exist for both managers:

```
df = df.query('ManagerID == 17 | ManagerID == 18')
#another solution for filter 
#df = df.query('ManagerID in [17, 18]')
emp = (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['EmployeeID','ManagerID'])
        .pivot('EmployeeID','ManagerID','ProjectID')
        .dropna()
        .index
        .tolist())
print (emp)
[2, 6]
```

Comment: This is indeed what I'm looking for. Thank you for the pivot approach, I was fixed trying to merge join.